# Can I push an element into a model's array during creation in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When doing this, I just get an empty array for list_employee in the database. So, is it possible to push an element when creating the house database?
If it is not possible, would it be best to use findOneandUpdate after creating it?

Here is my code:

```
module.exports.addHouse = async (req, resp) => {
    const {
        landLord,
        email,
        landLordPhone,
        address1,
        address2,
        city,
        numEmployees,
        state,
        zip,
        numBeds,
        numMattress, 
        numTables,
        preferredName, 
        firstName,
        tenantsPhone,
    } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        const createTenants = await Tenants.create({ preferredName, firstName, tenantsPhone });
        const createFacility = await Facility.create({ numBeds, numMattress, numTables });
        const createHouse = await House.create({ landLord, email, landLordPhone, address1, address2, city, numEmployees, state, zip, $push: { list_employee: createTenants._id}, facilityInfo:  createFacility._id })
        resp.status(200).json({house: createHouse});
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        resp.status(200).send('error')
    }
}
```

Here is the model:

```
const houseSchema = new Schema({
    landLord: String, 
    email: String,
    landLordPhone: String,
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    city: String,
    numEmployees: String,
    state: {
        type: String,
    },
    zip: String,
    list_employee: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: Tenants
    }],
    facilityInfo: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: Facility
    },
    // numReports: [{
    //     type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    //     ref: FacilityReports,
    // }]
});
```

```
const tenantSchema = new Schema({
    preferredName: String, 
    firstName: String,
    tenantsPhone: String,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there from my understanding things like `$push` is for updating, not insertion. Since you are using push on a newly created row in the database you wouldn't need to use push as it's empty in the first place.

Looking at the MongoDB Driver API `$push` is an array **update** operator

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/